# SQL - Group By columns that all have a distinct value

Tags: sql

I want group columns by their values and their distinct values.

Let's say that I have this data set.

```
| id| userId | date     | type |  
| 1 | 1000   | 20180501 | c |  
| 2 | 1001   | 20180501 | c |  
| 3 | 1002   | 20180501 | c |  
| 4 | 1001   | 20180501 | c |  
| 5 | 1005   | 20180501 | c |
```

The way that I want this to be group is that it starts to group them by type.
So it starts to group the columns with ids 1, 2, 3 but the forth column has the same userId with the second column so it doesn't group this one with the rest but it groups the last column because it has a different id.

Edit:

Thank you guys for the edit.I am currently running the last version of mysql and based on these data what i want to be returned is this:

| 5 | 1005 | 20180501 | c | 4 |
| 4 | 1001 | 20180501 | c | 1 |

The last column basically counts the rows that it grouped.

Comment: Please provide table structures and format your data better.  Also what SQL are you using?  MS, MY, Oracle, etc?

Comment: What result set are you looking for?

Comment: Sorry about the format and thanks for editing it. I am using mysql and i want to be returned the newest row based on the date of the group.

Comment: Learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: But what is the problem? I described everything that i want.